# Add new webcontent version in Liferay

Tags: java, liferay, portlet

I would like to edit a webcontent (journalarticle) in Liferay and create a new version from that from a custom portlet. I call the `JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.addArticle()` method with the following relevant parameters:

```
articleId = article.getArticleId();
autoArticleId = false;
version = article.getVersion()+0.1;
```

So the old articleId, and the version increased.

This code works in LR 6.1.30EE, but in 6.1.20EE and 6.1.1CE I got a `DuplicateArticleIdException`. Is this a bug in the earlier version? Is there a workaround or another method to create a new version of an existing webcontent programatically?

Minor question: what is the correct mode of increasing the version? The above +0.1 way creates from v1.1 v1.200000000000002, but simply v1.2 would be preferable.

Note:
`updateArticle()` method with a new version does not work either, it throws `ArticleVersionException`. It seems the right behavoiur as it should update already existing content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I find a solution meanwhile, thanks to some inspiration by Andew Jardin from Liferay Forums.

The solution is quite simple: call `JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.updateArticle()`, but with the old version. Liferay automatically decides when to create a new version, and takes care of assigning the right version.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  I am getting this same error, LR 6.2sp11.  In my case, I am fetching the article, getting the version with `.getVersion()`, and passing that returned version directly to `updateArticle()`.  If I manually increment the version, I get an error saying LR couldn't find the article.  If I pass the original version, I get the `ArticleVersionException` with no other description as to what is wrong.

Comment: I am doing the same, passing the return value of `.getVersion()` to `updateArticle()`. Are you sure that you are fetching the latest version of the article? (E.g. by using `JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.getLatestArticle()`)

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved by doing ,

```
double version =    article.getVersion();
            version = MathUtil.format(version + 0.1, 1, 1);
            article.setVersion(version);
```